# Surjectivity for $g\circ f$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I have a presentation tomorrow and I need to be 100% certain that I have done this exercise correctly to pass the course. My teacher is especially big on motivating every step. Please correct me if you see anything that is wrong or if you think that something can be better explained.

**The exercise:**

Let $E, F$ and $G$ be given sets and let the functions $f\colon E \to F$ and $g\colon F \to G$ be given. Consider the following claim.

> If $f$ is surjective and $g$ is surjective, then $g \circ f$ is surjective.

**My Solution:**

$g \circ f$ can be rewritten as $g(f(x))$.

Since $f$ is surjective it means that for every $y \in F$, there is a pre-image in $E$ (a $y \in E$) such that $f(y) = z$.

Since $g$ also is surjective it means that for every $z \in G$ there is a pre-image $y \in F$ such that $g(y) = z$.

So, $f(x)=y$ and $g(y)=z$.

We now substitute $y$ in $g(y)$ with $f(x)$ and get $g(f(x))=z$.

This means that for every $z \in G$ there is an $x \in E$ such that $g(f(x))=z$.

This proves that $g \circ f$ is surjective and that the claim is true.

Comment: Looks like a copy of [this proof](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=16&ved=2ahUKEwiWxcvSx_HnAhUwPewKHdPoAlsQFjAPegQIAxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.fsu.edu%2F~wooland%2Fmad2104f12%2Fintegers%2FproofPDFs%2Fsurjective_pf.pdf&usg=AOvVaw34Wx-xIiqYiw6j-UXEDfT2). If I were your teacher I would aks an example for it, to see what you have really understood. For example, a counterexample: $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=1/x$ is surjective, but $g\circ f\equiv 1$ is not.

Comment: I think that I am more clear in my explanations. More motivations with words and better structure, for newbies like myself to understand.

Comment: Yes, but posting here and talking, say, at the blackboard are tow different things.

Comment: Yes that's probably true

Comment: If you see anything thats wrong, please let me know

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things on terminology.

The sentence "$g\circ f$ can be written as $g(f(x))$'' does not make any sense. I would rather say "the function $g \circ f$ maps an element $x \in E$ to $g(f(x))$''.

Formally, "preimage'' refers to a set, not to an element. I would say that given $z \in G$ there is an element $y$ in $F$ such that $g(y) = z$. You can say that $y$ is an element in the preimage of the set $\{z\} \in \mathrm{Im}(g) = G$.